# Reuse results from correlated subqueries in same query

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery

I have 4 tables (I actually have lots more that I want to do this with...but this is where I am starting).

- `distr_catalogs`: has many `distr_catalog_brands`, `distr_catalog_system_types`
- `distr_catalog_brands`: belongs to `distr_catalogs`
- `distr_catalog_system_types`: belongs to `distr_catalogs`
- `brand_catalog_sections`: belongs to `distr_catalog_brands`, `distr_catalog_system_types`

I am wanting to create a materialized view whose columns are:

```
catalog_id | catalog_name | brand_ids | system_type_ids | catalog_sections
```

- `catalog_id` & `catalog_name` come from the `distr_catalog` table
- `brand_ids` holds an array of the brand ids related to the catalog
- `system_type_ids` holds an array the system type ids related to the catalog
- `catalog_sections` holds an array of brand catalog section ids that are related to the `brand_ids` and `system_type_ids`

I can do all but the last just fine:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW catalog_system_brands AS
select dc.id as catalog_id, dc.catalog_name, 
ARRAY(SELECT brand_id FROM distr_catalog_brands WHERE distr_catalog_id = dc.id) as brands,
ARRAY(SELECT id FROM distr_catalog_system_types WHERE display_status = true AND distr_catalog_id = dc.id) as system_type_ids,
from distr_catalogs dc
```

This gets me a great table that has all the right data. However the only way I can figure out to get the last column I need ... is to completely re-write the subqueries in the final array statement. I get an error every time I try to use the `brands` or `system_type_ids` aliases I defined in the two above arrays.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW catalog_system_brands AS
select dc.id as catalog_id, dc.catalog_name, 
ARRAY(SELECT brand_id FROM distr_catalog_brands WHERE distr_catalog_id = dc.id) as brands,
ARRAY(SELECT id FROM distr_catalog_system_types WHERE display_status = true AND distr_catalog_id = dc.id) as system_type_ids,
ARRAY(SELECT id FROM brand_catalog_sections 
      WHERE brand_id = ANY(SELECT brand_id FROM distr_catalog_brands WHERE distr_catalog_id = dc.id)
      AND system_type_id = ANY(SELECT system_type_id FROM distr_catalog_system_types WHERE display_status = true AND distr_catalog_id = dc.id)) as section_ids
from distr_catalogs dc
```

How would I re-write the create statement to not have to re-run the subqueries?

*Note*: This is the first instance of this. However, the next table I bring into this view will need to use the results of the `section_ids` column to determine which systems to display. So this will get out of hand quickly if I am not able to reuse the results from a previous query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LATERAL` joins instead of *correlated subqueries*. This way you can reuse results to join to more tables:

```
SELECT dc.id AS catalog_id
     , dc.catalog_name
     , db.brands
     , ds.system_type_ids
     , bs.section_ids
FROM   distr_catalogs dc
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(SELECT brand_id
                FROM   distr_catalog_brands
                WHERE  distr_catalog_id = dc.id) AS brands
   ) db
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY (
      SELECT id
      FROM   distr_catalog_system_types
      WHERE  display_status = true
      AND    distr_catalog_id = dc.id
      ) AS system_type_ids
   ) ds
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT id
      FROM   brand_catalog_sections 
      WHERE  brand_id       = ANY(db.brands)
      AND    system_type_id = ANY(ds.system_type_ids)
      ) AS section_ids
   ) bs;
```

It's safe to use `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` (or just `, LATERAL`) here, because the array constructor always returns a row. Else, if a lateral subquery could come up empty (no row), you would use `LEFT JOIN LATERAL (...) ON true` to avoid losing rows.

Related:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [Postgres datetime sort slow and not using index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/124614/postgres-datetime-sort-slow-and-not-using-index/124667#124667)
- [Build JSON object from one-to-many relationship data in a single query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144102/build-json-object-from-one-to-many-relationship-data-in-a-single-query/144156#144156)